# KendoUI Accordion not getting expanded in iPad

Tags: javascript, ipad, scroll, kendo-ui, rubber-band

I have a web application running on iPad. This application contains a [Kendo UI Accordion](http://demos.kendoui.com/web/panelbar/api.html) inside it.

When the content of the page is more than the size of the screen and when I want to scroll, normal page scrolling happens (*as expected*). But when try to scroll the Kendo Accordion, the page scrolling happens instead of accordion scrolling (*unexpected*).

I was able partly handle this issue by applying [solution given by Chris Barr](http://chris-barr.com/2010/05/scrolling_a_overflowauto_element_on_a_touch_screen_device/).

After applying this solution the accordion is getting scrolled instead of the whole page which I wanted.

But the problem is when I click the items on the Accordion, the accordion item doesn't get expanded. How can I get to work this.

```
function touchScroll(id){
if(isTouchDevice()){ //if touch events exist...
    var el=document.getElementById(id);
    var scrollStartPos=0;

    document.getElementById(id).addEventListener("touchstart", function(event) {
        scrollStartPos=this.scrollTop+event.touches[0].pageY;
        event.preventDefault();
    },false);

    document.getElementById(id).addEventListener("touchmove", function(event) {
        this.scrollTop=scrollStartPos-event.touches[0].pageY;
        event.preventDefault();
    },false);
}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `event.preventDefault()` in `touchstart` event listener. It will allow you to click on links inside the scrollable area.